# Visitors with at least 1 event click? (Visits with Events)

Tags: google-analytics, visitors, event-tracking

I might be getting a bit too lost in the metrics to realize that I already have the numbers I'm looking for, but I'm trying to figure out how to report the number of unique visitors who visited a page that interacted with a specific element and caused an 'event click' on a page (So # of visitors who caused an event).

I currently have a dashboard set up with a widget that reports, in a table, the number of Unique Visitors by Event Category. However if there are multiple labels ('Next', 'Back', 'More Info') are the multiple labels messing with the visitor number that Analytics is reporting?

So say we have a slideshow on our page (along with some other content); I just want to see the number of 'Unique Visitors' that clicked ANYTHING on that slideshow. So Person A clicks 'Next' - that registers are 1 unique visit. Person B clicks 'Next', 'Back', and 'More' - so now we're up to two Unique visits. Person C visits the page but doesn't click anything, so we're still at 2 unique visits.

I...might already have this down with my widget...but the metrics are seriously scrambling my brains. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to do individualized tracking, there was a good discussion about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030780/is-it-possible-to-use-google-analytics-to-track-single-user-account) on Stack Overflow, in which you would need to add additional info to your current tracking tag to identify a user as User-X.

You would essentially be setting up a custom variable to track each user, and could then filter based on that custom variable. They also discuss the privacy terms of service associated with Google Analytics which you don't want to violate.

> However if there are multiple labels ('Next', 'Back', 'More Info') are
>   the multiple labels messing with the visitor number that Analytics is
>   reporting?

Event tracking would only interfere with your bounce rate (i.e., if a visitor looked at only one page but clicked on an item with an event that would no longer be a bounce as they interacted with the page), but it wouldn't mess with your visitor count - see [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#Count) for more.

Instead, you would see the same number of unique visitors with a varying unique event count. If user A clicked the Back button 5 times, you would have 5 events for the Back button but only 1 unique event and only 1 unique visitor. As stated above, check out the Stack Overflow thread and look into adding some sort of custom variable so you can see more detailed information to what UserX is doing.

A widget of unique visitors with a secondary of unique events would give you two numbers you could divide to see the average number of unique events performed by unique visitors.

Comment: Thanks for your post, it's informative - but I'm not entirely sure solves my particular question.  Ultimately what I'm looking for is 'Visits with Event'.  Analytics will provide me with this number in the Event Overview section, but it's for ALL my event categories.  What I can't seem to find is how to syphon it down to a single Category.  For Example - In event overview I have 200,000 Visits w/ Events total; but what I really need is how many Visits w/ Events for only 'Involvement Box'.

Comment: In your widget use the "filter this data" option. Set to Event Category only containing and then the word you'd like to filter for, in your example "involvement box." You'd need to create multiple widgets, or you could use Analytics shortcuts (there's a shortcut button in the gray bar across the top) to save a page you've looked at within the Behavior -> Events section

Comment: Awesome. That's how I had my widget set up initially (Unique Visits filtered by a specific Category - like Involvement Box) - I just wasn't sure if that was a legit number for what I was looking for. The only problem now is I take that filter away - and it displays unique visitors for each Category - totally up those visitors winds up being much, much, much, lower than the 200,000 total number the overview page gives me.